# How to implement D3 Zoomable Icicle in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I trying to apply this **D3 Zoomable Icicle** chart to my Vue2 App, but it's not working.
https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle.

The documents is so hard for me to understand, try about one day but nothing work.

I am quite new to D3 so would be very grateful if someone can give me an example.
Thank you